# how to show viewcontroller: UIImagePickController and dismiss it (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uipickerviewcontroller

i got this uiactionsheet which loads uipickerviewcontroller
its in a viewcontroller thats in a UISplitViewController

It's a UIsplitviewcontroller, this code is on a detailview, the detailview is called from masterview

how ever, when i try to load it "click it" it gives me a warning and doesnt go any further

```
   func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    switch buttonIndex{

    case 0:
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        NSLog("Vælg fra Biblioteket");
        break;
    case 1:
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        NSLog("Vælg Kamera");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog("Default");
        break;
    }
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) // this is the problem 
}
```

the warning is this : Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting (null)

how ever if i use this : 
    self.showDeatilViewController(imagePicker, true) it show up but then i can't dismiss it at all

here's how i thought it would be dismissed

```
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

If i run this code in viewDidLoad, it works

```
        var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: { imageP in

    })
```

I figured out that if i write this :

```
        self.presentedViewController?.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it shows and closes ?!?!

Comment: What is self in this ?

Comment: @CW0007007 it's in a uisplitviewcontroller, i forgot to mention... how ever i think self is the Detailviewcontroller in the uisplitviewcontroller

Comment: is it the master view in the split view ?

Comment: @CW0007007 no detailview

Comment: Surely the detailViewController is the detail view and self is the master ?

Comment: Erm well when you made it you must have set it up ?

Comment: @CW0007007 It's a UIsplitviewcontroller, this code is on a detailview, the detailview is called from masterview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it working... someone brought to my attention that 8.0 IOS has a bug with opening the photolibery and such from apps..
so i put it in the main queue like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and now it works!

little delay but it works